# O(E) shortest path

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, shortest-path, bellman-ford

Is there a way to find the shortest path from a single source to a vertex in a graph with arbitrary weights in O(E) but you only need to worry about it if the shortest path has 7 edges or less.

Bellman-Ford algorithm has a best case run time of O(E), would that apply here?

Comment: complexity is the same, you just need to modify the algorithm correspondingly. the execution time is going to be even faster because lots of cases are pruned away

Answer (score 1):

If you know the shortest paths with <= **N** steps to all vertices, then it's easy to calculate the shortest paths with <= **N+1** steps by iterating over the edges and evaluating the longer paths you could make with each one.

At **N=0**, the shortest path to the source vertex has length **0** and the shortest paths to all other vertices have length **infinity** (i.e., you can't get there).  You only have to iterate over the edges **7** times to find the shortest paths to everywhere you can get in <= **N=7** steps, for a total running time of **O(E)** if you're a little bit careful about your data structures.